# How to fix contacts whose First names were saved as Last names?

Tags: replace, contacts, textwrangler, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to fix someone else's contacts (which I retrieved from their phone), but it seems that many, many contacts have their First names also written in the Last name field. Probably the phone was asking in turn for each piece of information and the Last name was the first.

Could someone please help me sort this database? I can export from Address Book a large .vcf, which I can open in Text Wrangler, but the application is quite new to me and I don't think Excel (can't use it with vcf) formulas help.

I haven't used Text Wrangler much but tried to look in the manual. Since I couldn't find something through "search", I gave up skimming the manual.

Could someone please help me make Text Wrangler detect the space between the first and last names and move the last name, if it's the case, before a semicolon?

Edit: There also are some cards without last names, but, again, the first name is written instead in there. So if there is one word (name) in the last name field, it should be moved instead to first name. If there are two (names/words separated by a space), then the first should be moved in another label.

This is what one such card (first name in last name)

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Alex Instal;;;;
FN:Alex Instal
TEL;type=CELL;type=pref:nananana
X-ABUID:F9246772-nana-nana-nnana-nananana\:ABPerson
END:VCARD
```

And a correctly formatted one

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Reynold;Adrian;;;
FN:Adrian Reynold
TEL;type=CELL;type=pref:nananan
X-ABUID:221697DB-3960-nana-nana-nanananana\:ABPerson
END:VCARD
```

Comment: Do you have an algorithm to reliably detect what is a first name? (I certainly don't).

Comment: Oh, I forgot. No, I don't, but I see she noted every person First Name Last Name. "Instal" is not a family name- I guess it comes from "Installation" (rather _Installateur_), but that's the rule, most have their names written like this, except it's entirely in the "Last name" field.

Comment: Can you split the names on the semi colon after N: ? As in `N:Reynold;Adrian;`

Comment: What do you mean? Yes, that's what I want, but I don't know how to write a script (find-and replace kind) for Text Wrangler. I want to open the vcf and edit it through the script in Text Wrangler. all I know is the order of the values between the semicolons:
Last;First;Middle;Prefix

Comment: Let's take the example of [Clarissa Jean-Philippe](http://www.lemonde.fr/societe/video/2015/01/20/solennite-lors-des-funerailles-de-clarissa-jean-philippe-tuee-a-montrouge_4559942_3224.html), the policewoman killed (at Montrouge) in recent terrorist attacks in France. Without context, there is no way to know what part of the name "Clarissa" or "Jean-Philippe" is the family name. So I believe you cannot have a reliable algorithm to sort that out. Your algorithm will be imperfect. You could use machine learning or neural network techniques using a *large* database of known vcards.

Comment: I told you, she knew which was which, wrote all the contacts in the right order. If one's name is Richard Hopkins, she wrote Richard (First Name, birth-name, prénom) and Hopkins after (surname/family name/Last name). All contacts in this order. But she said Last Name: Richard Hopkins, not First:Richards and Last:Hopkins.

Comment: Then, put the database in some SQL database (e.g. [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)...) and sort it correctly; or perhaps use [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)

Comment: Thank you. Well, I guess I'll read TextWrangler's manual and learn to use find and replace. Or maybe convert the vcf to something else and work it out in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regular expression with back-references that will work for the Alex Instal case you described. First make sure that the `grep` option on the TextWrangler search dialog is checked. Search for this:

`^N:(\w*)(\s)(\w*);;;;$`

and replace with this:

`N:\1;\3;;;`

Whether this will work for you of course depends on how consistent your file format is and whether there are any special cases like middle names, etc. But this will at least work for the case described and you could tweak it if necessary.